# TypeError: Student() takes no arguments

Tags: python

i'm just beginning to learn python and am getting this "TypeError: Student() takes no arguments." Can someone help me out as to whats wrong with my code?

(In Student.py file)

```
class Student:
    def __init_(self,name,major,gpa,is_on_probation):
        self.name = name
        self.major = major
        self.gpa = gpa
        self.is_on_probation = is_on_probation
```

(In app.py file)

```
from Student import Student

student1 = Student("Jim", "Businesss", 3.1, False)

print(student1)
```

Comment: You're missing an underscore. The method should be `__init__(...)`, with two underscores on each side.

Comment: With the typo, `Student.__init__` resolves to the inherited method `object.__init__`, which takes no arguments. The error message doesn't make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

Init need 2 underscore on each side :

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,major,gpa,is_on_probation):
        self.name = name
        self.major = major
        self.gpa = gpa
        self.is_on_probation = is_on_probation
```

Answer (score 3):

As people pointed out in the comments, you missed an underscore in the constructor of the Student class.
This is the correct version.

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, major, gpa, is_on_probation):
        self.name = name
        self.major = major
        self.gpa = gpa
        self.is_on_probation = is_on_probation
```